# DropdownButton and DropdownMenuItem height, how to reduce the gap between the items when in dense mode?

Tags: flutter

I'm using the standard DropdownButton in Flutter. Is there a way to reduce the size between each item?  I've reduced the size of the button text and padding by setting the isDense property to true.  However the individual items listed when the dropdown text is selected has a very large amount of padding.

Is there a way to reduce this padding?

https://dartpad.dev/?id=35c3d089d76887a3b5e8ffc0c45a4766

[image]

```
          DropdownButton<String>(
            value: 'one',
            isDense: true,
            onChanged: (String? value) => print('on change'),
            items: ['one', 'two', 'three'].map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>(
              (value) {
                return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                  value: value,
                  child: Text(value, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 5)),
                );
              },
            ).toList(),
          )
```

Comment: It should be the `itemHeight` property, but the assertion has prevented us to set it below 48

Comment: Oh yes, right you are @DhafinRayhan !  Do you know whether there is a github issue for this in the Flutter repo?  It can't be by design having the button reducing in size with the isDense property while the item heights remain the same.